# Group By session Id linq and How Data Store into observable collection?

Tags: linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my Observable Collection Object

```
    private ObservableCollection<StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup> _usageLogGroup;
    public ObservableCollection<StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup> UsageLogGroup
    {
        get
        {
            if (_usageLogGroup == null)
            {
                _usageLogGroup = new ObservableCollection<StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup>();
            }
            return _usageLogGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            _usageLogGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UsageLogGroup");
        }
    }
```

In below code i have created session id linq and store all data in to "data" variable ,I want to store this data variable record on my observable collection ."UsageLogGroup"

```
if (res.userLogDetails?.Count > 0)
                    {
                        UsageLogsList = new ObservableCollection<StatisticsUsageLog>(res.userLogDetails);                       
                         var data = UsageLogsList.GroupBy(u => u.SessionId).ToList();

                        //I want to store varible "data" to ObservableCollection "UsageLogGroup"

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UsageLogsList = new ObservableCollection<StatisticsUsageLog>();

                        CustomProgressDialog.Instance.HideLoading();
                        // await DialogService.ShowAlertAsync(AppResources.NoEntreisFoundMsg, AppResources.TitleAlert, AppResources.FlagOk);
             

   }
```

Comment: Whats the actual issue you are facing? can you explain a bit more like in which thing you need help

Comment: I want to store variable data into observable collection,My Varible name is "data" and My Observable collection name is "UsageLogGroup" ,I have show in my quetion,Issue is When i am try store data in collection show

Comment: UsageLogGroup  = UsageLogsList.GroupBy(u => u.SessionId).ToList();  show error in UsageLogGroup  bcz this is observable collection ,

Comment: these are two collections of completely different types

Comment: I agree with Jason, both the collections are of different type, so you can’t assign one collection value to another

Comment: So what can I do, I want to display Group By session id data bind to my xaml page that's why I want collection

Comment: There's no reason you can't group that data, but these appear to be two different types of data.  It's impossible to say for sure because you haven't posted the code for either class.

Comment: Is `StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup` sub-class of `StatisticsUsageLog`. If yes, then you can achieve that.

Comment: yes .statisticUsagelog is sub class for StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup

Comment: Can you show the code of statisticUsagelog  and StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup  ? and provide demonstration what  are you expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup` class is created like below

```
public class StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }

    public List<StatisticsUsageLog> List { get; set; }
}
```

Modify your code as below

```
var data = UsageLogsList.GroupBy(u => u.SessionId,(key,g) => new { SessionId = key, List = g.ToList()}).ToList();


foreach (var item in data)
{
    UsageLogGroup.Add(new StatisticsUsageLogSessionGroup
    {
       SessionId = item.SessionId,
       List = item.List
    });
}
```